# Behat feature files in a separate git repo

Tags: git, behat, mink

We have a lot of PHP web applications and websites.  I have created a behat/mink setup that will work for all of our apps/sites.  I want all sites to share a common testing setup so I want to have the /test folder under each project as a Git submodule that contains the behat/mink setup as well as the features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php that I have customized for our sites.  BUT I want the .feature files to remain as part of the app Git repo.

How can I pull this off?

If is simply add *.feature to a .gitignore inside test, the submodule will ignore them but so does the project repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your feature files outside your submodule with the following configuration:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths:
                - %paths.base%/../features
```

Then your submodule containing the shared configuration could be in `/test/behat` while the feature files are placed in `/test/features` and are part of the main repository.

Comment: I like this.  Simple and straightforward.